# What does exclamation mark mean inside Intern's define?

Tags: javascript, intern

When looking at the Intern.io examples, I'm not following the path syntax.

For example:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
```

What's going on with the '!' character?

```
// Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
suites: [ 'intern/node_modules/dojo/has!host-browser?tests/utils' ],
```

Can someone explain the path reference above for the suite path?

Thanks.

Comment: The exclamation marks are specifying particular modules to load.

Comment: @steve_gallagher that's the answer, post it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Module IDs with exclamation points are [AMD loader plugins](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/LoaderPlugins.md). The part before the exclamation point is the module ID of the loader plugin module, and the part after the exclamation point is plugin-specific information that the plugin module uses to decide what to do.

- `intern!object` loads the `intern` plugin module and then tells it "object" (which causes the plugin to load the object interface API)
- `intern/chai!assert` loads the `intern/chai` plugin module (and tells it to load the assert-style API)
- `intern/dojo/has!host-browser?tests/utils` (there should not be a `node_modules` in this mid) loads the `dojo/has` module from Intern’s internal copy of Dojo, and uses it to load `tests/utils` if the `host-browser` feature detection test is true (otherwise it loads nothing).

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation marks are specifying particular modules to load.

The path reference allows an [alternative AMD loader](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Configuring-Intern#useloader) to be used.